# Foreach array inside array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I show only name and lastname for mecanicien?

```
$aMecaniciens = array(
    array(
        "idMecanicien"=>1,
        'vchNomMecanicien'=>"Guérand",
        'vchPrenomMecanicien'=>"Bob"

        ),
    array(
        "idMecanicien"=>2,
        'vchNomMecanicien'=>"Lim",
        'vchPrenomMecanicien'=>"Bao"

        ),
    array(
        "idMecanicien"=>3,
        'vchNomMecanicien'=>"Cadoret",
        'vchPrenomMecanicien'=>"Cadoret"

        )
    );

foreach ($aMecaniciens as $value) {

    foreach ($value as $key) {
        echo "<option value=\"value\">$key[1].$key[2]</option>";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using `$key[1]`, but the arrays are not with a numbered index. Try using `$key['vchNomMecanicien']` instead.

Comment: @Qirel `$key` does not hold the inner array, it holds things like `Guérand` and `3`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the inner `foreach`. You can use the named keys of `$value` to output your options.

```
foreach ($aMecaniciens as $value) {
    echo "<option value=\"$value[idMecanicien]\">
              $value[vchNomMecanicien].$value[vchPrenomMecanicien]
          </option>";
}
```

With the nested loop you will output three options for each item in `$aMecaniciens`, which I assume you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($aMecaniciens as $key => $value){
 echo '<option value="'.$value['idMecanicien'].'">'.$value['vchNomMecanicien'].' '.$value['vchPrenomMecanicien'].'</option>';
}
```